# downloading CSV file in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to download a csv file to python. For some reason I can not do it. I suppose I need to add an additional argument to read_csv?

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UofGAnalyticsData/"\
          "DPIP/main/assesment_datasets/assessment3/starwars.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: works for me. What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: It creates a dataframe and assigns it to a variable named `df`. You can see a sample of the contents of this dataframe with `print(df.head())`

Comment: Try to print df with `print(df)` to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

The code you attempt is downloading the content from the url and pasting it in the data frame named 'df'.
You need to save the output csv by using the following line. You will find the output file in the same directory where the python script is saved.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UofGAnalyticsData/"\
          "DPIP/main/assesment_datasets/assessment3/starwars.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```